# Most efficient way to get a subset of values from a table?

Tags: sql, performance, dbeaver

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    accountNumber,
    event, --can be anything
    day_id --date
);

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES (123, 'start', 20211010),
       (123, 'finish', 20211010),
       (123, 'finish', 20211010)
       (123, 'jump', 20211010),
       (124, 'run', 20211011),
       (155, 'skip' 20211010);
```

There can be any combination of duplicates.

I would like grab a subset from the table that is a list of all accountNumbers which DID start and finish, but did NOT jump. To achieve this, I have the following:

```
with cte as (select accountNumber from table1 where event = 'start'),--cte with all accountNumbers that had 'start' at one point
cte2 as (select accountNumber from table1 where event = 'finish'), --cte with all accountNumbers that had 'finish' at one point
cte3 as (select accountNumber from table1 where = 'jump') --cte with all accountNumbers that jumped

select distinct accountNumber from table1
where accountNumber in (select * from cte)
and accountNumber in (select * from cte2)
and accountNumber not in (select * from cte3);
```

This is slow. Especially if I scale it up to include more conditions. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want all AccountNumber that has `start` and `finish` events but not `jump` events.
So Simply try this:

```
select Distinct accountNumber from table1 t1
where (event = 'start' or event = 'finish') 
And not Exists (select accountNumber from table1 t2 where event = 'jump' and t1.accountNumber = t2.accountNumber)
```

The result is equal to your query.